# Calling a Jframe object from a closing JDialog object

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am creating a basic Swing application. In which I have a `JFrame` (which has a `JTable`). This window has add record button, where I open a `JDialog` window which has few data field. Once the use enter the value for those fields. I need to add those information as a record in the `JTable` with in the `JFrame`.

To do this, I open the `JFrame` window. Once the user press 'Add' button. The `JDialogbox` window opens (While the `JFrame` is still open in the background). Then user enters some information and it needs to be pass back to the `JFrame`.

How can I do this without having to create a new `JFrame` object. Is there any way to use the parent element in the `JDialog` box constructor?

```
(javax.swing.JFrame parent, boolean modal)
```

Comment: Are you talking about `JDialog` ?

Comment: Yes, Mainly how to communicate from the JDialog to the JFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a skeleton of code that shows a way to achieve what you want using a callback method on your frame.

```
public class DataBean{
     // keep all variables that needs to be transferred
}

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
      // Frame code here

     public void openDialog() {
          new MyDialog(this,true).setVisible(true);
     }

    public void addRowToTable(DataBean data) {
       // add row to table from data 
    }
}

public class MyDialog extends JDialog {
    // Dialog display code

    DataBean data = new DataBean();
    // populate DataBean object from dialog fields
    // dispose dialog
    // call method to pass
    ((MyFrame)getOwner()).addRowToTable(data);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad that helped you. have fun coding :)